# You are selected or you have selected. What is the difference between these two?

Tags: grammar

I have written:

> you have shortlisted for ABC company.

But when I searched, I did not understand whether it is:

> you have shortlisted

Or:

> you are shortlisted

Gives the same meaning? Is the first sentence totally wrong?

Comment: If the company have put you on a shortlist of applicants for a job, you _are_ or _have been_ shortlisted. The company have shortlisted 5 applicants (or however many it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "shortlist" someone is to put them on a "short list" for further investigation.

So it is company ABC which "shortlists" you.

If that happens, then "you have been shortlisted by ABC."

or, to put it another way:

"ABC have shortlisted you."

And as a result, "you are shortlisted".

That is, your status is that of being a "shortlisted person".

Comment: You have shortlisted for ABC company. Is it correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Please read what I wrote.